# Explain the estimated residual variance in a Gamma mixed model, using glmer()

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, residuals, glmm, deviance

I am applying a generalized mix model, where the response has a gamma distribution, as below:

```
fit <- glmer(score ~ treatment + (1 | site) + (1 | group), family = Gamma(link = log), data = dat, nAGQ = 1L)
```

The model output `summary(fit)` or `VarCorr(fit2)` gives the estimated variance of the random intercepts and residuals. I am wondering what is the estimated residual variance in terms of Gamma distribution? Is it the estimated deviance residual?

thanks

```
Random effects:


Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 site   (Intercept) 0.14551  0.3815  
 group  (Intercept) 0.03931  0.1983  
Residual            0.09286  0.3047
```

Answer (score 1):

The default family in `glmer()` is `gaussian()`. Hence, the model you fit is actually a linear mixed model, and not a Gamma model. To fit a Gamma mixed model you will need to specify `glmer(..., family = Gamma())`

Moreover, have a look at the corresponding section of the [GLMM FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#gamma-glmms). In general, Gamma mixed models are problematic, and perhaps it would be better to use a linear mixed model for the log-transformed data.

Comment: thanks for the comments. I have corrected my code in the question. Can you give more insights on possible issues with Gamma GLMM? In my case, it does provide better residual diagnosis.